# What are the differences for the prestige raid?

Tags: destiny-2

The prestige version of the Leviathan raid was released with some small changes and new tweaks to make it harder. Besides enemies simply being higher level and therefore tougher to kill, what are the main differences and mechanical changes between the normal and prestige version of the raid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Pretige mode has a recommended power level of 300, and enemies do much more damage.
- You lose your Revive token if you use it, or if you die and haven't used it yet.
- Gear drops at 300 power level
- A new Prestige set of armor drops. There are no normal drops if you do the Prestige mode first.
- New Shader
- Royal Baths

  - The Bathers drop a pool on the ground when they are killed that removes stacks of your buff
  - More Bathers spawn during the DPS phase
  - After each dos phase, 4 random players get a debuff, and a symbol spawns in the middle of the room. The symbol indicates which plate you must stand on.
- Pleasure Gardens

  - There are 8 Beasts (instead of 6). They have slightly different patrol routes.
- Gauntlet

  - A Psionic Projection spawns along with the Psion (when the runner goes through a gate), and both must be killed.
  - Everyone must be a runner. Once you've ran once, you get a debut preventing you from running again.
  - In the final round (when everyone runs), there are only 3 orbs instead of 4 at each gate.
- Calus

  - When someone melees a psion in the Throne Room, that player gets teleported to the Mind's Eye and someone in the Mind's Eye gets teleported back to the Throne Room.
- The Prestige mode emblem drops after your first clear
- You get an Aura that is usable until the next weekly reset after finishing the raid

(Based on [Datto's Prestige Mode video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zr5f4_9tjJ4)).